# Cumsum with groupby for date accumulation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, cumsum

I am trying to sum the number of categories for each month and cumulate the previous months. The group by needs to be by month,year, and category. I tried different ways of using cumsum but I just can't get it.

This is the df:

```
sample=[
{'name':11,'category':'A','year':2017,'month':1},
{'name':22,'category':'A','year':2017,'month':2},
{'name':33,'category':'B','year':2015,'month':1},
{'name':33,'category':'C','year':2017,'month':3},
{'name':33,'category':'B','year':2017,'month':8},
{'name':44,'category':'B','year':2016,'month':4},
{'name':44,'category':'A','year':2017,'month':6},
{'name':55,'category':'C','year':2016,'month':9},
{'name':55,'category':'C','year':2017,'month':5},
{'name':55,'category':'B','year':2017,'month':11}]

sample_df=pd.DataFrame(sample)
```

I grouped by month,year, and category and aggregated by month

```
sample_counts = sample_df.groupby(['month','year','category']).agg({
                                    'category': 'count',
                                }).rename(columns={'category':'category_count'}).reset_index()
```

The output of sample_counts is this:

```
month   year  category  category_count
1       2015     B         1
1       2017     A         1
2       2017     A         1
3       2017     C         1
4       2016     B         1
5       2017     C         1
6       2017     A         1
8       2017     B         1
9       2016     C         1
11      2017     B         1
```

So I want the output to add all the B's (for example) as the months progress

**So by 11/2017 the 'B' sum should be 2.**

I tried different variations of

```
cumul_df=sample_counts.groupby(['month','year','category']).sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum().reset_index()
```

I would like the **FINAL output** to look like this (only showing for 2017 below, but 2016 and 2018 would be the same logic and look and would be in the same table below):

```
Category    Month        Year       Cumulative_By_Category               
A            1            2017       1
A            2            2017       2
A            3            2017       2
A            4            2017       2
A            5            2017       2
A            6            2017       3    
A            7            2017       3 
A            8            2017       3
A            9            2017       3
A            10           2017       3
A            11           2017       3
A            12           2017       3
B            1            2017       0
B            2            2017       0
B            3            2017       0
B            4            2017       0
B            5            2017       0
B            6            2017       0
B            7            2017       0
B            8            2017       1
B            9            2017       1  
B            10           2017       1
B            11           2017       2
B            12           2017       2
C            1            2017       0
C            2            2017       0
C            3            2017       1
C            4            2017       1
C            5            2017       2
C            6            2017       2
C            7            2017       2
C            8            2017       2
C            9            2017       2
C            10           2017       2
C            11           2017       2
C            12           2017       2
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Hi, I posted the output for what 2017 would look like. Didn't want to make it longer by adding 2016 and 2018 as it's the same logic/look

Comment: still hard to understand ..why A in 2017 do not have 0

Comment: Because for January 2017 category A existed. But B and C did not so they are 0

Comment: it's cumulating per month per category for each year

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is just `cumcount`:

```
sample_df['cat_count'] = sample_df.groupby(['year','category']).cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
   name category  year  month  cat_count
0    11        A  2017      1          1
1    22        A  2017      2          2
2    33        B  2015      1          1
3    33        C  2017      3          1
4    33        B  2017      8          1
5    44        B  2016      4          1
6    44        A  2017      6          3
7    55        C  2016      9          1
8    55        C  2017      5          2
9    55        B  2017     11          2
```

Comment: Hi thank you for responding. Could you explain why it's not cumsum but cumcount?  I am not understanding why you add 1. Also, don't I need to specify to count by the category type? Thanks again!

Comment: `cumcount` starts from `1`. You are `cumsum` on the `1` values, which is the same with enumeration, i.e. `cumsum`.

Comment: hm, Also don't I need to specify the category so the function knows I want to group by category as well as year and month?

Comment: The solution of course would change if you have multiple instances of same category per `(year, month)` pair. In which case, **you need to groupby month**, and your approach is correct, except that you should use `cumsum` in the second attempt.

Comment: Hi, I posted an output example for 2017, I think based on what you showed, maybe cumcount doesn't work for my purposes either? I think I need to create a loop through the group by and customize it to look like my output